# What does the URL option do when creating a new launcher in the DartEditor?

Tags: dart, launcher, dart-editor

How does the URL option work when creating a new launcher in the DartEditor.

I know, when running the launcher, the browser opens up the specified URL. But what does the "Source location" do? What it's purpose?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When using the HTML file option Dart Editor will use the built-in web server to serve files. If you already have a web server set up you can use the URL option to debug from the specified URL and source.

Comment: Could you please elaborate how "to debug from the specified URL and source" works, if using an own webserver?

Comment: For instance, if you had a server running on 8080 you could specify as the URL `http://localhost:8080/somefile.html` and then for the source you would select the folder containing that code. Dart Editor will now be able to debug that URL and give your error messages.